# How can I draw a choke valve?

Tags: engineering

I'm trying to replicate this choke valve figure for my molecular thermodynamics notes.

[image: choke valve]

However, I'm relatively new to tikz, and I'm struggling to replicate the little "cylinder" attached to the piston (I marked what I'm talking about).

[image]

I tried to change the width of the cylinder, but I couldn't reduce it as I was expecting. How can I fix it?

Here is my code so far:

```
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{xlop}
    \usepackage{float}
    
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            % Left "cylinder"
            \node[draw, left color = gray!90, right color = gray!80, middle color = gray!40, shape = rectangle, minimum width = 0.01 cm, minimum height = 2 cm, anchor = center, rotate = 90] at (-2.600, 0.000) {};
            % Right "cylinder"
            \node[draw, left color = gray!90, right color = gray!80, middle color = gray!40, shape = rectangle, minimum width = 0.01 cm, minimum height = 2 cm, anchor = center, rotate = 90] at (3.100, 0.000) {};
            % Room for the piston
            \node[draw, shape = rectangle, minimum width = 8.5 cm, minimum height = 2 cm, anchor = center] at (0.000,0.000) {};
            % Left piston
            \node[draw, left color = gray!90, right color = gray!80, middle color = gray!40, shape = rectangle, minimum width = 2 cm, minimum height = 0.4 cm, anchor = center, rotate = 90] at (-1.500, 0.000) {};
            % Right piston
            \node[draw, left color = gray!90, right color = gray!80, middle color = gray!40, shape = rectangle, minimum width = 2 cm, minimum height = 0.4 cm, anchor = center, rotate = 90] at (2.000, 0.000) {};
            % Initial volume
            \node[draw, fill = gray!25, shape = rectangle, minimum width = 2 cm, minimum height = 0.6 cm, anchor = center, rotate = 90] at (-0.850, 0.000) {};
            % Choke valve area
            \node[draw, fill = orange!70, shape = rectangle, minimum width = 2 cm, minimum height = 0.2 cm, anchor = center, rotate = 90] at (-0.300, 0.000) {};
            %  Final volume
            \node[draw, fill = gray!25, shape = rectangle, minimum width = 2 cm, minimum height = 1.4 cm, anchor = center, rotate = 90] at (0.750, 0.000) {};
            % nodes
            \draw[-]  ( 1.425,  1.200) -- ( 1.425,  1.500);
            \draw[-]  ( 0.050,  1.200) -- ( 0.050,  1.500);
            \draw[-]  ( 0.050,  1.350) -- ( 1.425,  1.350) node[midway, fill = white]{$V_{f}$};
            \draw[-]  (-1.150,  1.200) -- (-1.150,  1.500);
            \draw[-]  (-0.550,  1.200) -- (-0.550,  1.500);
            \draw[-]  (-1.150,  1.350) -- (-0.550,  1.350) node[midway, fill = white]{$V_{0}$};
            \draw[->] (-0.300, -1.500) -- (-0.300, -1.100);
            \node at  (-0.850,  0.000) {$P_{0}$};
            \node at  ( 0.700,  0.000) {$P_{f}$};
            \node at  (-0.300, -1.700) {\small{válvula de estrangulamiento}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With the code shown, I'm getting the following figure:

[image]

I appreciate any help or advice to improve the figure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, 2[inner sep] is the absolute minimum space taken up by a node, so set [inner sep=0pt] when using [minimum height] and [minimum width] (no text).

Second, it seems the shadings are applied after the rotation.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage{amsthm}% not used
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{graphicx}% redunctant
%\usepackage{tikz}% redundant
%\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{xlop}
%\usepackage{float}
    
    \usetikzlibrary{shadings}
    
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            % Left "cylinder"
            \node[draw, top color = gray!90, bottom color = gray!80, middle color = gray!40, shape = rectangle, minimum height = 0.1 cm, minimum width = 2 cm, inner sep=0pt, anchor = center] at (-2.600, 0.000) {};
            % Right "cylinder"
            \node[draw, top color = gray!90, bottom color = gray!80, middle color = gray!40, shape = rectangle, minimum height = 0.1 cm, minimum width = 2 cm, inner sep=0pt, anchor = center] at (3.100, 0.000) {};
            % Room for the piston
            \node[draw, shape = rectangle, minimum width = 8.5 cm, minimum height = 2 cm, anchor = center] at (0.000,0.000) {};
            % Left piston
            \node[draw, top color = gray!90, bottom color = gray!80, middle color = gray!40, shape = rectangle, minimum height = 2 cm, minimum width = 0.4 cm, inner sep=0pt, anchor = center] at (-1.500, 0.000) {};
            % Right piston
            \node[draw, top color = gray!90, bottom color = gray!80, middle color = gray!40, shape = rectangle, minimum height = 2 cm, minimum width = 0.4 cm, inner sep=0pt, anchor = center] at (2.000, 0.000) {};
            % Initial volume
            \node[draw, fill = gray!25, shape = rectangle, minimum width = 2 cm, minimum height = 0.6 cm, anchor = center, rotate = 90] at (-0.850, 0.000) {};
            % Choke valve area
            \node[draw, fill = orange!70, shape = rectangle, minimum width = 2 cm, minimum height = 0.2 cm, anchor = center, rotate = 90] at (-0.300, 0.000) {};
            %  Final volume
            \node[draw, fill = gray!25, shape = rectangle, minimum width = 2 cm, minimum height = 1.4 cm, anchor = center, rotate = 90] at (0.750, 0.000) {};
            % nodes
            \draw[-]  ( 1.425,  1.200) -- ( 1.425,  1.500);
            \draw[-]  ( 0.050,  1.200) -- ( 0.050,  1.500);
            \draw[-]  ( 0.050,  1.350) -- ( 1.425,  1.350) node[midway, fill = white]{$V_{f}$};
            \draw[-]  (-1.150,  1.200) -- (-1.150,  1.500);
            \draw[-]  (-0.550,  1.200) -- (-0.550,  1.500);
            \draw[-]  (-1.150,  1.350) -- (-0.550,  1.350) node[midway, fill = white]{$V_{0}$};
            \draw[->] (-0.300, -1.500) -- (-0.300, -1.100);
            \node at  (-0.850,  0.000) {$P_{0}$};
            \node at  ( 0.700,  0.000) {$P_{f}$};
            \node at  (-0.300, -1.700) {\small{válvula de estrangulamiento}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I might add that you could replace all those absolute coordinates with named and relative coordinates, working left to right.  I just didn't want to spend that much time fixing it.